# CMS page, much text dont work to save

Tags: database, cms

CMS page, much text dont work to save. 
When I save a cms page with a few letters, about 3792 characters.
It works, but when I try to save the cms page with about 4000 characters, it did not work when I did this in the backend.
It says that it will be saved in the backend, but it will not.

However, if I log into my database, myphpadmin, I add the text there under the cms page. And it works.

I'm on a VPS,  I can not server config
 
Ideas?

1.9.2.4

Comment: does it happen for any 4000 chars? Maybe there is something special about char 3793.

Comment: no special char,

Answer (score 0):

Change the cms content column from text to longtext this should fix your issues

Comment: This i really wierd,
i have copied the shop to an shared server, and it works there,
i have also copied it to an synology nas, and it works.
and all have mediumtext, like the VPS.

now have i installed wordpress on VPS, and i has the same problem, with many Words/chars.

Comment: Technically I think your VPS. May have been modified as max limit on mediumtext is 16MB or it could be the character formatting on the column

Comment: Thanks. I gonna check this with my "hotell" if they can help me.